# Facebook - Page feed using a cron

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cron

How to generate user access token for cron?

If I manualy generate user acces token [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token)

I get this https://graph.facebook.com/475587132530747?fields=videos&access_token=CAACUjjG5ux0BACuotPrrMdFVWoqextT2TJd3LfrcZBLKN4cPa6FcF36YLkZAy9O78SCakzweH9eAIj8wZCHvb3CavagzPELvr6e3ntATzEHpCe9wxWmPLXYA5oHmk0UxelqZBqtsxc505axLLBAN5yfzPMpfzUdsdNFcqwO5a4XOZBZC2g905rQrvGgrJtVXIZD

That's ok, but this token has expired in 1 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot generate a user access token without the users activity. Facebook changed the validity of user access tokens to be 60 days maximum (extended), so an app that is not used by the user anymore does not have access to his profile anymore. It would be useless to limit the validity if it would be able to regenerate it with a cron job.

More information about tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

What you may need is an extended access token.

Comment: So it can't be done via cron fully automatic saving posts to the database?

Comment: well, you cannot generate a user access token with a cron job, but you can - with a valid user access token - use that token in a cron job. at least for 60 days, then you need a new token with user interaction. but be careful what you store, because of privacy issue. you shouldn´t just grab everything the user posts, in fact you should ask the user for every single post if he allows it.